# C API for Couch DB and example documentation

Tags: couchdb

I want to know if there is a good C API library for Couch DB which has good documentation for the following:
1. Find
2. Creation of indexes
3. Insert
4. Remove

I've used mongoDB and it was perfect fit, I found its C API, but later realized that it wasn't good for my requirements, since my database will be in a 32 bit server, and DB size will be around 20 GB.

Please help me point to the C API link, and documentation of how to write code using that API. Its a nightmare trying to find good documentation or API for NOSQL databases, and I've already spent couple of days, but of no avail (except for mongodB). Please help.

Comment: maybe you can roll your own using curl?

Answer (score 1):

There is a C API based on curl and yajl:

https://github.com/jubos/pillowtalk

There are examples here:
http://www.sevenforge.com/pillowtalk/

However, pillowtalk has not seen updates in a while, and it looks like it only supports POSTs to named documents. I was looking for guile bindings, couldn't find them, and then looked for C ones. I don't think this lib currently meets my requirements, either, but it's a good start.